# Handling subclasses and variables in PHP

Tags: php, class, inheritance, instance-variables

So, what I want to do is have a class library for an `orderprocess`, where the `orderprocess` consists of different parts, like address, personal information, etc etc. So my code should look a bit like this:

```
$process = new orderprocess();
print $process->orderpart("address");
```

And then I want the `orderpart()` function to be a bit like:

```
public function orderpart($part){
    $name = "orderprocess_" . $part;
    $class = new $name();
    return $class;
}
```

Only thing is, the mother class, `orderprocess` has a number of public and protected variables, which I want the subclass to inherit or access. So it would have variables to track the status of the form, so the initial code would then look like this:

```
$process = new orderprocess();
print $process->orderpart("address");
if ($process->status["address"] == "done"){
   print $process->orderpart("personal");
}
```

Meaning that the parent `orderprocess` class need to keep track of things in its child classes.

"Extend" only extends the functionality of the parent class, not the instance as far as I'm aware. I would like the `orderpart()` function to create a new subclass which extends the parent class *and* inherits or can access the parent's variables of the *instance* of the parent class.

Please advise if you think I'm going about this in the wrong way as well.

Comment: I see you've edited the problem with my code below. Did it work for you? What else are you looking for?

Comment: My question concerns the topic of inheritance of class instance variables, not how to call a subclass, it was bad form on my part to not write it correctly making you focus on the code instead of the problem :)

Comment: Would this requirement be appropriately handled using the [Chain-of-responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)? If so, there are standard ways of implementing this pattern n PHP, that may be worth investigating.

Comment: @Sandman have you tried putting the track status in the parent class and just calling it from the subclass? The phrasing of your question is not quite clear but I believe that should work in this case

Answer (score 0):

Just define your entire classname first:

```
public function orderpart($part){
    $classname = "orderprocess_" . $part;
    return new $classname();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your phrasing is quite confusing but maybe this is what you're looking for.

```
class Parent
{

   protected $status;

    public function __construct(){
      /* Set status to whatever here */
    }

    public function orderpart($part)
    {
       return "orderprocess_" . $part;
    }

    public function status($part)
    {
      if ($this->status[$part] == "done"){
        return $process->orderpart("personal");
      }
       return false;
    }
}

class SubClass extends Parent
{
    public function orderpart($string)
    {
        return "orderprocess_" . $part;
    }
}
```

Then you can just call this I believe:

```
$SubClass->status($part);
```